# App to find the shortest route with the least amount of climbs?

Tags: bikeroutes

I want to go from point A to point B avoiding climbs, but also take the shortest route possible with the fewest climbs.  Does any mobile app exist that can find the shortest route and with the lowest sum-total amount of elevation change between two places?

Comment: Conflicting requirements.  Minimum distance between two points will have the maximum slope.

Comment: Perhaps it's not maximum slope that's concerning but rather the sum of any required climbs?

Comment: yes @Ross the priority is the minimum slop

Comment: Minimum slope(grad) is not the same as sum of any required climbs.  There is only one shortest route between two points.  You cannot have shortest route and anything else.

Comment: I suspect what the OP is looking for is the shortest distance with the least amount of climbs involved.  First priority would be given to the sum of all climbs in the route, and the second priority would be the shortest distance.  Am I right, @dimit?

Comment: yes exactly that @digijim

Comment: I've made some edits to reflect this distinction.  Feel free to correct/remove if needed.

Comment: its ok , as you can see my english is very poor

Comment: Better English that many Americans, unfortunately.  You probably should add "in Greece" to the end of the title to attract more specific answers.  I should have done that in my edit.

Comment: The only app I've even caught wind of similar to what you're asking is the hammerhead app. I am not sure if you have to have the hammerhead itself, but allegedly you can put in preferences like you're requesting (shortest with least climbing). You might investigate it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strava has this feature in the route planning tool.

In the header, you can see it has toggle switches for **popularity** (pretty nifty if the area is new to you), **min-elevation** (what you're looking for), and **manual**.

[image]

Here is an example of how it works. The below route is between two points in Palos Verde, CA - a notoriously hilly (fun) area.

**Min Elevation OFF:**
[image]

**Min Elevation ON:** Here's the route with the same end points and the feature turned on -- a savings of 348 feet of elevation gain, but an extra 2.5 miles of riding.
[image]

Comment: nice.. this feature is only in the pro version?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I have the free version. It's under Dashboard > My Routes > New Route

Comment: Fast forward to May 2021: "Route Planning" does indeed now require a subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps has a bike route feature that displays elevation and tries to find the least-steep and most bike-friendly path between points by default.

1. Go to Google Maps at http://maps.google.com.
2. Select Directions.
3. Type your starting address.
4. Type your destination.
5. Click "..." to the left of the Directions icon, then click the bicycling icon.
6. Customize the route by dragging the blue line (your bike route) wherever

Comment: I am in Greece and here i can't get bike directions with google maps.

Comment: Several possible alternatives may be listed here:  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/154/where-can-i-find-local-bike-routes?rq=1

Comment: Interesting answer, I wasn't aware that Google published their "default" metrics (such as minimising climbs). Do you have any more info?

Comment: Found this relatively thorough explanation of all the factors that go into determining the 'ideal' route:  http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2010/03/its-time-to-bike.html  Granted, it is 5 years old, but it's also posted by a Google engineer from the Directions team.

Comment: Great start, and has to be targeted at an average person, but everyone is different - I am a strong climber and relatively weak on the flat, so do better on hills than my peers. Others hate hills and would double the distance to avoid a climb.  In the end a route calculator would need to provide choices for the user to select from.